# bit manipulation procedure precedence doesn't seem right

Tags: c, operators, bit-manipulation

```
x = ++2<<4%3*3
```

So i assumed that by precedence :

1. List item
2. ++2
3. 4%3
4. what is get in (2) *3.

but then i wondered doesn't ++2 mean increase x by 2? so the answer would be in terms of x :S ?

PLEASE NOTE: this is not a code im trying to compile its, a question i have had problems in at a written coding excercise where im supposed to calculate x.

Comment: Add a space and it will compile `x = + +2<<4%3*3` --> `16`, but then it may not be the value hoped for.

Comment: this is a question im trying to solve i didnt create it.

Comment: OK, then rewrite it or ignore it, it's rubbish code.  Don't waste your own, or anyone else's, time on it.

Comment: Oh.. an exercise.  OK, then you should sort it out.  This is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers. A professional would get fired for going near such code, an enthusiast would be too ashamed to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

> then i wondered doesn't ++2 mean increase x by 2?

No. `++2` is illegal. The pre-increment can be used only with an expression that evaluates to an lvalue.

Comment: so how do i go about solving this then?

Comment: @CcoderBeginner, you can divide that line into multiple, simpler, steps. It's not clear from your code what you intend to assign to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

> but then i wondered doesn't ++2 mean increase x by 2?

No; it attempts to increment the literal `2` (which is not allowed).  `x += 2` increases `x` by 2.

Perhaps you (or the person you got the code from) meant to write

```
x += 2 << 4 % 3 * 3; // whitespace is your friend, use it
```

in which case, you're adding 16 to `x`:

```
x += ( 2 << ( ( 4 % 3 ) * 3 ) )
x += ( 2 << ( 1 * 3 ) )
x += ( 2 << 3 )
x += 16
```